# Background color doesn't change CSS Style sheet

Tags: html, css, background-color

```css
body { background-color: bisque;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reading</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>  
        <button><a href="index.html">Home</a></button>  
        <button><a href="reading.html">Reading</a><br/></button>
        <button><a href="coffee.html">Coffee</a></button>
    </h1>
    <div>
        <h1>I usually drink three to four cups of coffee on weekdays</h1>
        <img src="cof1.JPG" height="171" width="294"
                alt="Coffee"/> 
        <img src="cof2.JPG" height="168" width="300"
                alt="Coffee"/>   

        <h2>Some of my favorite coffees are: </h2>
        <OL>
            <LI> Cafe Crema</LI>
            <LI>Yaucono</LI>
            <LI>Arabigo</LI>
            <LI>Cafe Lareño</LI>
            <LI>Mami</LI>
        </OL>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried many styles to see what's wrong, but I can't seem to change the background color. This webpage works, but it's just plain. I am required to use CSS in order to compare both styles.

Answer (score 1):

I copy and paste you're code and its working fine 
i guess the problem is that you didn't refresh the page 
try to do hard reload
CTRL+ F5 or in mac command+R

Answer (score 0):

It actually does. I edited your question so it should be a snippet, and it worked in your source too. The only change I made was to change the `p` tag into `div` tag since `p` tag is meant for a paragraph, and what you wanted is a block.

Look how I changed the background color to blue:

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reading</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>  
        <button><a href="index.html">Home</a></button>  
        <button><a href="reading.html">Reading</a><br/></button>
        <button><a href="coffee.html">Coffee</a></button>
    </h1>
    <div>
        <h1>I usually drink three to four cups of coffee on weekdays</h1>
        <img src="cof1.JPG" height="171" width="294"
                alt="Coffee"/> 
        <img src="cof2.JPG" height="168" width="300"
                alt="Coffee"/>   

        <h2>Some of my favorite coffees are: </h2>
        <OL>
            <LI> Cafe Crema</LI>
            <LI>Yaucono</LI>
            <LI>Arabigo</LI>
            <LI>Cafe Lareño</LI>
            <LI>Mami</LI>
        </OL>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't change for me.

EDIT: 
It worked, thank you!

Comment: When you run the code snippet in my answer, don't you see the background color blue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page is not refreshing right

```
PRESS Ctrl + F5
```